# Xamarin.Android android:versionCode android:versionName - From Jenkins Build Server

Tags: android, jenkins, msbuild, xamarin.android, xamarin

We have a unique situation where we are deploying a Xamarin.Android app to China to 33 app stores. Hence, our solution has 33 application projects, and we setup Jenkins (running on Windows) to package and sign all our apks (otherwise it would be crazy to make builds).

We also need to modify `android:versionCode` and `android:versionName` in the manifest file, by using the `${SVN_REVISION}` value from Jenkins. Is there a way to pass these values command line to MSBuild?

Normally we would hand edit this value, but it's not possible because of so many application projects.

Our build parameters right now look like this in Jenkins:

```
/p:Configuration=Release;AndroidKeyStore=True;AndroidSigningKeyStore=ourkeystore.keystore;AndroidSigningStorePass=ourpassword;AndroidSigningKeyAlias=ouralias;AndroidSigningKeyPass=ourpassword /t:SignAndroidPackage
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this to the end of your *.csproj file, before the ending `</Project>` tag:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild" Condition=" '$(JENKINS)' == '1' ">
    <XmlPoke XmlInputPath="Properties\AndroidManifest.xml" Namespaces="&lt;Namespace Prefix='android' Uri='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android' /&gt;" Query="manifest/@android:versionCode" Value="$(SVN_REVISION)" />
    <XmlPoke XmlInputPath="Properties\AndroidManifest.xml" Namespaces="&lt;Namespace Prefix='android' Uri='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android' /&gt;" Query="manifest/@android:versionName" Value="2.0.$(SVN_REVISION)" />
  </Target>
```

I have Jenkins configured to pass JENKINS=1 and SVN_REVISION. When it goes to build, it modifies `AndroidManifest.xml` before the build.

I don't know if this will work on xbuild on a Mac or not, depends on if `XmlPoke` is implemented. I should do a blog post on this.

Answer (score 1):

No. You'll have to manipulate the `android:versionCode` and `android:versionName` yourself. Personally, I use a rake task to handle this particular detail.

Comment: There are a lot of examples using `ant` for Java. I would really just like to do it command line without using a script, but I guess there is no other way.

Comment: Sir, you give up too easy. We have the power of `MSBuild`.

Comment: I build on OS X w/xbuild being called from rake. We'll leave the debate on the "power" of MSBuild for the next time we meet in person.  :)